# Why is "Search the web" NOT an option for "What do you do when you get stuck on a problem?" in the survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2020

When asked "What do you do when you get stuck on a problem", "Use google" / "Search the web" is not an option!?

My guess is "using google" would be the most popular answer.

**Why is it not an option?**
Can it be added in?

There are sites other than Stack Overflow that are also useful to developers, so my goto action is searching the web.

I cannot be in the minority here; because Stack Overflow's "search" functionality is almost useless, you have to use google anyway to find Stack Overflow answers to your questions. Plus you can find other stuff.

I would guess that "using google" is what *most* people in *most* walks of life do when stuck on a problem.

And btw why were "Meditation", "Going for a walk" and other "humorous" options *included*? If you want serious results, collect serious data.

---

Digging a little deeper:

- Is there any QA process for survey content?
- If so (doubtful), exactly who reviews it? Do reviewers have any connection or understanding of the world of development?
- Why is the proposed survey not posted on meta first to allow feedback from the community? Not saying that feedback needs to be acted on, but it would catch errors like this.

Still deeper:

Why is “Ask a colleague” NOT an option?
Isn’t that one of the main reasons that we work in teams? So we an support each other?

For me, “Search the web” and “Ask a colleague” are the *only* things I do when needing help to solve a problem.

Comment: Yes, search the web is what I put into the free text box.  Like Duh?  Oh wait, is this a negative comment?

Comment: Even if I wanted to search just SO I'd still use Google or another proper search engine. Was a bit surprised that option was missing myself.

Comment: SO's search is basically useless. It uses no tech invented after 1990, especially not stemming search terms or handling spelling variations. AFAICT it converts your search terms to not much more than `where (content like '%term1%' or content like '%term2%') and mytag in tags order by case when content like '%term1%' then 1 else 0 end + case when content like '%term2%' then 1 else 0 end desc` or similar. How sad for a site that has within it Q+A's that tell how to implement search properly!

Comment: First I debug, then I go to google. Neither of those are options in the survey.

Comment: It's also weird that it mentions "I watch videos" as a way to learn about problem/solution yet it doesn't have...reading. I don't like videos - I prefer written content, as it's way easier to skim and find appropriate part or use as reference. You know what tends to be documented in written form? *Documentation*. I don't need to watch a video for how to use some API if there already is comprehensive documentation. SO also happens to be in written form.

Comment: @VLAZ "SO also happens to be in written form" - don't give them ideas.

Comment: I was surprised at this too! And same with what @VLAZ said. I reread the options a couple of times to make sure I hadn't missed something before I wrote in "Google and read things."

Comment: Indeed @VLAZ I'm not sure I've *ever* watched a video on how to write some piece of code. Plenty of Googling and reading documentation though.

Comment: Does it include an option to ["Ask the Duck"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ?

Comment: @chris No; the duck was not an option. I am often the “duck” in my work life. I try to take full credit for solving the problem, putting it down to the strong quantum solution field that I emanate.

Comment: So: no debug., no google, no read the docs, no ask the duck, no ask a colleague... looks like I'll need to order a truck load of salt for when (if!) I read the survey results.

Comment: You asked *"Is there any QA process for survey content?"*. Last year  I was invited to answer a early version of the survey and to give my feedback.

Comment: @adrian My question was entirely rhetorical - there’s no way this question went through any kind of QA process, or if it did stackoverflow’s corporate team has hit a new industry low in the field of surveys. I’m curious, was any of your feedback incorporated into the final version?

Comment: A little I think. I did try and compare my feedback to the final survey and, I think there were some changes. I remember being concerned with the wording of some questions about gender. They used words that, with my UK background, seemed rude. Beyond that I am afraid that I cannot remember.

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue too. I fixed it easily by going to "Other" and typing in "Google".

Comment: I wouldn’t call it “fixed”. More like “failed” if 99.99% had to take the same, profoundly obvious workaround.